# How to create a graph of function in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a graph of cost function in matplotlib.

Cost function looks like this:
[image]

and the graph should look like this:
[image]

I have written this code to create the graph in matplotlib:

```
xs=[]
ys=[]
for x in range(1,11):
    y=0.00001*(x**3)-0.003*(x**2)+5*x+1000
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)
tuples=list(zip(xs,ys))
df=pd.DataFrame(tuples,columns=["x","y"])
df.plot(kind="line",x="x",y="y",figsize=(15,5))
plt.show()
```

and the graph itself looks like this:
[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I get the same distinct shape as in the first graph?

Comment: looks about what I'd expect. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The expected picture seems to be wrong. According to my calculation, the inflection point should be at x=1000.

Comment: It seems `0.00001` is not `10^{-6}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy or numpy-like code to make it much easier to write numerical code.

Also, I write `1e-6` here to make sure I use the correct coefficient given by your equation.

```py
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
ys = 1e-6*(xs**3) - 0.003*(xs**2) + 5*xs + 1000

plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

If you want a dataframe, that's ok too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": xs, "y": ys})
df.plot(kind="line",x="x",y="y",figsize=(15,5))
plt.show()
```

Now that the code is simpler, it's easy for you to change the X range and plot the function for another interval - maybe using `xs = np.linspace(0, 1500, 100)`.

[image]